# How can i proof my results after mine some dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification

I wonder if there´s anyway to proof the correctness of my results after apply some data mining algorithms to a set of data. When i say data mining algorithms im talking about the [basic algorithms](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/10Algorithms-08.pdf)

Comment: Proof has a very formal meaning that I doubt you're intending. Can you be more specific? Do you want to demonstrate consistency? Show that the accuracy of the method cannot be below x? Give guarantees on running time? Estimate worst-case performance?

Comment: Approximation results are never "correct" but they can be "accurate". There is no universal definition for "high accuracy" so you can't prove much there. Can you clarify what exactly you want to show?

Comment: @BenAllison I want to Proof(formal sense) that my results are right and i didnt know that i can show that the accuracy of the metoth cannot be below some x, how can i do that?

Comment: Look at constructing a confidence interval for whatever performance statistic you care about. Beware statistical assumptions!

Answer (score 0):

If you have many examples, a simple way is to split available data in three partitions:

- training data (around 50%-60% of available examples, randomly chosen);
- validation data (20%-25%);
- test data (20%-25%).

Training data are used to adjust parameters of the data mining algorithms.

With validation data you can compare models/algorithms/parameters and choose a winner.

Test data can give you a forecast of winner's performance in the "real world" because they are independent (during the training/validation phase you don't make any choice based on test data).

Anyway there are many schemes and probably the best place to delve deeper into the matter is http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There can be several ways to proof correctness of your results. Firstly, you have to choose  performance criteria

1. Accuracy of algorithm
2. Standard Deviation of results
3. Computation time

Based on either of these criteria, you have to adopt different-different mechanism to prove correctness of your algorithm.

**1. Accuracy of algorithm**
  for this you have to understand, what are those point which can be questioned when you say that my algorithm's accuracy is XY.WZ%.

*First question, is your algorithm giving better result because of over-fitting?*
To avoid over-fitting by your algorithm, you can divide your data into three parts

1. training data
2. validation data
3. testing data

by doing so, if you are get good testing results, you can be sure that your algorithm did not over-fit. if there is a big difference between training and testing accuracy that is a sign of over-fitting.

*What if you find out that your algorithm over-fit?*

You can use several regularization techniques that keeps value of weights coefficient lower and helps in preventing over-fitting. You can know more about this in lectures of machine learning by Andre N.G at coursra.

*Second question, is your data-set fairly chosen?*

Suppose you have 100 dataset and you divided it in 50-30-20 set (training-validation-testing). Now question comes which 50 for training and which 30 dataset for validation and so on. So for different-2 selection of these data-set, you will get different-2 accuracy values. So, you should take 5-10 different-2 sets and then provide and average of results. This technique is known as cross-validation technique.

An another way to prove correctness of your algorithm is to provide confusion matrix in case of muticlass classification and sensitivity and specificity in case of binary classification. you can look at their wiki pages.

**2. Standard deviation of results**
If your algorithm is based on random population generation or based on heuristics then you are most likely to get different solution at each run of algorithm . In this case, you should provide an standard deviation of multiple runs on same data-set and same parameter setting by your algorithm.

**3. computation time of algorithm**
This might not be important in every case but if you are doing an comparison of your algorithm with other algorithm then you should provide comparison of computation time, however this has nothing to do with correctness of your algorithm but it does gives an idea of comprehensiveness of your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

### What good are proven results?

At most you will be able to prove that your implementation matches some theoretical mathematical model, or that an approximative algorithm approximates this mathematical model.

But in practise, real data will not satisfy your mathematical assumptions anyway.

Often, the best proof is: **does it work**?

That is, on *real*, *unseen* data. Not on the data that you used to choose your parameters, because then you are prone to overfitting.